# How to remove specific value in tensor?

Tags: pytorch

If I have the tensor like this,

```
tensor([[2, 5, 4, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 5],
        [4, 0, 1, 5, 0, 3, 5, 1, 4],
        [1, 1, 7, 2, 1, 5, 1, 1, 1],
        [5, 5, 5, 3, 0, 4, 3, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 5, 3, 2, 7, 3],
        [6, 6, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]])
```

I wanted to remove value '1' as many as i can
so desired tensor is like this

```
tensor([[2., 5., 4., 2., 5., 1., 1.],
        [4., 0., 5., 0., 3., 5., 4.],
        [7., 2., 5., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
        [5., 5., 5., 3., 0., 4., 3.],
        [5., 3., 2., 7., 3., 1., 1.],
        [6., 6., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.]])
```

how to make original tensor to desired tensor effectively?

I tried like this way,

```
>>> not_one = torch.sum(t!=1, dim=-1)
>>> max_l = not_one.max()
>>> not_one
tensor([5, 7, 3, 7, 5, 2])
>>> max_l
tensor(7)
>>> desired_tensor = torch.ones(t.size(0), max_l)
>>> for i, tt in enumerate(t):
...     desired_tensor[i, :not_one[i]] = tt[tt != 1]
... 
>>> desired_tensor
tensor([[2., 5., 4., 2., 5., 1., 1.],
        [4., 0., 5., 0., 3., 5., 4.],
        [7., 2., 5., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
        [5., 5., 5., 3., 0., 4., 3.],
        [5., 3., 2., 7., 3., 1., 1.],
        [6., 6., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.]])
```